# Error EACCES Permission Denied issue while deleting a index.lock file from .git folder

Tags: git

I m having issue while pushing the code to my github repo when  I try to push the code then
this issue appears

```
git add .
fatal: Unable to create '/home/naima/Documents/Projects/expense-tracker/.git/index.lock': Permission denied
```

So when I try to delete the index.lock file inside .git folder then it shows me another another which is:

```
error: EACCES permission denied .[error while deleting index.lock file[\]\[1\]][1]
```

[Error while pushing the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4khDp.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should not be deleting that lockfile, however, something that may be causing that issue is having your text editor open. Try closing it and pushing your commits.

Comment: I tried it after closing my text editor and it's not working.

Comment: Might not be just text editors. Any application that integrates with git can be causing this, including zombie processes on the machine that did not shut down properly. Application crashes can cause this.